# unable to edit content created by user 1

Tags: nodes

In drupal 6 I have created an admin user with the permissions to add, edit and delte all kind of nodes. The problem is that I am unable to edit nodes through this newly created admin user which are created by user1. any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

I think, you did not assign "edit any [contenttype] content" permission to newly created admin user, so this user does not have access to edit content created by other user.

You can follow below step for configurations.

- Go to Administer ->  User management -> Permission
- Assign "edit any [contenttype] content" permission to newly created admin role and save the permissions.

Kindly see that [contenttype] is content type in your website. If you want to allow newly created admin user to edit all content created by other user, you need to give permission for all content type.

Comment: Already mentioned that I have already defined the permission to that newly created admin role to add, edit or delete the nodes of all the content types like basic page, story, etc...

Comment: @Fahad, there is two type of edit permission, "edit own [content type] content" and "edit any [contenttype] content". If you provide "edit own [contenttype] content", then user is not able to edit content which is created by other user.

Comment: I completely understand your point, I have defined bothtype of permissions

Comment: @Fahad, which type of error you are getting when admin user tried to edit content created by user 1.

Comment: getting access denied error, although when I am creating content from user 1 I am also selecting user admin as an author

Comment: @Fahad, Did you check the user role of admin user? You can also check this after assign permission to authenticated user.